# Reading each line and copy it in a new file using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have text involving following data (more lines; ~10,000):

```
QRH
DDD
CFN
SPW
DNP
STM
FQF
PEW
CEG
NHE
...
..
.
```

I would like to copy each line in a new file and write in the second line "phe"

like this,

File 1:

```
QRH
phe
```

File 2:

```
DDD
phe
```

File 3:

```
CFN
phe
```

etc.

Would you please advise me on how to do it,

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following script should work. `input.txt` holds your list of data, and the output would be a set of files names of the form `File000001.txt`

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f_input:
    for index, entry in enumerate(f_input):
        with open("File%06d.txt" % (index+1), "w") as f_output:
            f_output.write(entry+"phe\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it woks well.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept one of the answers when you are ready, to collect your Scholar badge.